# REACT TypeError: this.props.chatroomlist is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, setstate, iterable

I am new to react and working on an assignment for building a chatroom app. Following is the error I am getting.

ChatroomManager.addChannel
src/comps/chat/ChatroomManager.js:

```
  21 | 
  22 |  this.setState( {
  23 |     
> 24 |    chatList: [...this.props.chatroomlist, this.state]
  25 |  
  26 |  })
  27 |
```

Given below is my code sample.

```
class ChatroomManager extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
        chatroomId:5,
        chatroomName:'pubad',
        chatroomType:'pub',
        relnType:'owner' 
    }
    this.addChannel = this.addChannel.bind(this);
}

addChannel () {
  this.setState( {        
     chatList: [...this.props.chatroomlist, this.state]
  })      
  console.log(this.state)
 }

render () {
  return (
    <div className="chatrooms">
      <ChatroomBox chatList={this.props.crlist}/>
      <div>                 
         <div className="input-group mb-3">
            <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Add Chat Rooom!"/>
             <button onClick={ () => this.addChannel () } type="submit">Add</button>                           
         </div>                   
       </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

}

Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: Make sure the ```this.props.chatroomList``` you are passing to set state is an array. Check the parent component or console log props to see

Comment: I think more context is needed. Please show the parent component that is rendering ChatroomManager. Also, as others have mentioned, Its often a smell when the shape of the state object is changed as in the `addChannel` method.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to declare the state which you want to set i.e chatList. You need to declare in this.state before setting it.

For using props you need to pass it from where you are mounting your component. Something like this -- <ChatroomManager chatroomlist:{} >

Comment: Both the things were done but error still continues to occur...

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using the so called `spread Operator` that is `...` before `this.props.chatroomlist`.

The thing is, `spread operator` can only be used for `javaScript Objects`.

Please check whether `chatroomlist` is an `Object`.

Objects are within  `{}`. And the error you get `TypeError` also adds that `chatroomlist` is not an `Object` hence cannot be spread or iterated.

If you have not declared a state `chatroomlist` then declare it as an `Object`

Comment: const chatroomlist = [
    {
        chatroomId: 3,
        chatroomName: 'bio',
        chatroomType: 'pvt',
        relnType: 'member' 
    },
    {
      .....
} ]
class ChatApp extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="chat-app">
                <NotificationManager/>
                <div className="chat-area">
                    <MessageManager/>
                    <ChatroomManager  crlist={chatroomlist}/>
        
                </div>
            </div>
       
        )
    }
}
export default ChatApp;

Comment: Try like this then.  `this.setState( {        
     chatList: [{...this.props.chatroomlist, this.state}]  // Add the {} brackets 
  })`

Comment: Does not work . ./src/comps/chat/ChatroomManager.js
  Line 25:53:  Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'

  23 |         this.setState( {
  24 |             
> 25 |            chatList: [ {...this.props.chatroomlist, this.state} ]
     |                                                     ^
  26 | 
  27 |          })